# Cannot connect to nginx server on fedora linux (digitalocean)

Tags: linux, nginx, fedora

I tried to set up nginx on a brand new fedora box on DigitalOcean. These are my steps

```
$ yum install nginx
$ systemctl enable nginx
$ systemctl restart nginx
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. I get the following output when running `systemctl status nginx`

```
[root@inspiredev ~]# systemctl status nginx -l
nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2014-11-07 14:26:33 EST; 1s ago
  Process: 958 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 967 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 966 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 970 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─970 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/ngin
           └─971 nginx: worker proces

Nov 07 14:26:33 inspiredev systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Nov 07 14:26:33 inspiredev nginx[966]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Nov 07 14:26:33 inspiredev nginx[966]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Nov 07 14:26:33 inspiredev systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Nov 07 14:26:33 inspiredev systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

I can't seem to figure out or where I went wrong. It'd be great if someone can help with this.

EDIT: When I go to the box's IP address, I got nothing, which is why I feel like something is not working right.

Comment: from the log you get, nginx seems to be left successfully in running state

Comment: @guido yeah, however when I go to the public IP of the box, I get nothing..

Comment: getting a blank page may indicate nginx did serve that page. try with curl or wget and see what you get.

Comment: @guido I don't get a blank page, I just don't get anything back. Chrome says "This webpage is not available", curl times out.

Comment: what about `curl http://localhost` from the rmeote box console?

Comment: at first I got the 403 Forbidden page. after a  few restarts I got the proper nginx welcome page. However the public IP is still not returning anything.

Comment: which means you need to open the firewall port....?

Comment: it should be on port 80 right? otherwise, I am not sure how to "open the firewall port" as you suggested.

Comment: `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http` followed by `systemctl restart firewalld.service` (if it is fedora 20), then try again

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! If you wanna rewrite that comment as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @guido btw, how can I open a different port rather than port 80?

Comment: using a variant of firewall-cmd, pls see answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the systemd logs, nginx service appears to be running. (the warning about the pid file not found seems endemic to many distributions).

On fedora 19/20 (systemd based), open the firewall with the following commands:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http 
systemctl restart firewalld.service
```

or alternatively:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp 
systemctl restart firewalld.service
```

The second version syntax lets you open any port/protocol combination.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue, didn't realize `firewalld` daemon was running.